# can i install windows two times on the same machine on two different storage places?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I want to install WIN10 on my SSD but I already have WIN10 on my HDD. Can I install WIN10 to the SSD while WIN10 is already installed on my HDD?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install two Windows operating systems on your PC. To start HDD operating system after SDD installation you have to configure the boot partition in **device manager -> disk management** .

If autoconfiguration succeeded in default windows bootloader ask to run operating system which you want to run. *(you have to be inserted both HDD and SDD on your PC while installing windows on your SDD.*